# Pyspark - Error calling pandas_udf returning a Series.interpolate() as result

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a UDF returning an [interpolation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html?highlight=interpolation) function, but the function is returning a Series, with index and throwing an exception.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

@F.pandas_udf(FloatType(), F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def udf_interpolate(v):
  return v.interpolate('linear')

## Test data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("charles", 1),
    ("charles", None),
    ("charles", 3),
], ["name", "value"])

window = Window.partitionBy('name').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn('test_interp', udf_interpolate(df.value).over(window)).show()
```

The error message:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Could not convert 0    3.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
Name: _0, dtype: float64 with type Series: tried to convert to float32
```

I tried to force the conversion to float32, but the error persists. My initial idea is because I'm returning a Series with multiple values in a 'one value expected' but I don't know exactly how to solve this problem.

If I change my function, for example, to return a `v.mean()`, works well.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`GROUPED_AGG` requires the UDF to return a scalar](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf); In your case, better to use a `GROUPED_MAP` since you are returning a Series and need to perform the calculation by group; Essentially you pass a sub data frame for each name to the `pandas_udf`, transform it with pandas API and return the transformed data frame back:

```
@F.pandas_udf(df.schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def udf_interpolate(g):
    return g.assign(value=g.value.interpolate('linear'))

df.groupby('name').apply(udf_interpolate).show()
+-------+-----+                                                                 
|   name|value|
+-------+-----+
|charles|    1|
|charles|    2|
|charles|    3|
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, @Psidom. Testing in Databricks, if I run the udf_interpolate 3 times using GROUPED_MAP, I have three different results (sometimes, the right one). Do you know why?

Comment: Very likely because your data frame doesn't have an inherent order. In practice you should have a column like a timestamp to order by.